Story about moving on in life?
Is there any story about a tragedy or something bad happening, yet someone moved on in life and continued fulfilling their duties? This can be from the Torah, but preferabally a more modern time story!

Not really modern but Rabbi Akiva losing 24k students and then persevering and starting again with 5 disciples

@Curious Yid - Interesting

The book of job

This is applicable to many millions of Jews who survived the holocaust, many losing literally their whole family, parents, wife, children l'a.

Aharon after the death of his sons in Parshas Shemini https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.10.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

@MichoelR - that was my purpose of this question - how'd you know :) I needed a story to go along with a Dvar Tora for Parshas Acherei Mos / Shemini!

I found this question understandable and worth keeping open

There are many books of this type that are on sale in modern book stores.

The best example I know is first-century rabbi Nachum ish Gamzu.  He was severely afflicted, yet always optimistic.  No matter what happened to him or around him, he would say: “Gam zu l'tovah -- This, too, is for the good”.  He always saw a silver lining and continued to teach, in particular Rabbi Akiva.  The Talmud recounts his story:

It is related of Nachum of Gamzu that he was blind in both his eyes, his two hands and legs were amputated, his whole body was covered with boils, and he was lying in a dilapidated house on a bed whose feet were standing in bowls of water to prevent the ants from crawling on to him… Why was he called Nachum of Gamzu?  Because whatever befell him he would declare, “Gam zu l’tovah -- This, too, is for the good.” [Taanit 21a]


There are endless stories of people overcoming struggles.  Here is one example - an autobiographical account of Rabbi Aharon Margalit, who overcame separation from his family, polio-induced disability, a debilitating stutter, serious cancer, and loss of a child.   I met him in person, and he is simply radiant.  Such a pleasant person to be around.
https://www.amazon.com/As-Long-Live-Aharon-Margalit/dp/1598268724
